# FFT of first N samples of signal?

Tags: dsp

Suppose if their are M samples in x(t) out of which I compute FFT of only first N samples of x(t), then the computed X[k] does this represent frequency component of first N samples or what I am doing is conceptually wrong?

Any concept clarification will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's hard for us to say if what you are doing is conceptually wrong, because you haven't explained what you are trying to do. What are you trying to accomplish by taking the FFT of the first N samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are computing is the [short time Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform)(STFT) of your signal x(t).If you take the STFT of the first M samples of your signal x[n], then what that STFT will represent will be the frequency components in the first M samples of x[n], this is not the same as the Fourier transform of the entire signal.